# Function opcode in C

Tags: c, hook

I was reading an article [x86 API hooking demystified](http://jbremer.org/x86-api-hooking-demystified/#ah-advanced) about x86 hooking, and I came across this code:

```
if(*function_A == 0xe9) {
    printf("Hook detected in function A.\n");
}
```

It seems that this code tests whether the opcode of the function is a jump. 
My question is about the syntax `*function_A`. what is this syntax? Does it return the opcode of a function in C? I made a lot of research but I didn't find any documentation on this feature

**EDIT**

I thought I added the link to the article but I just noticed I forgot to add it. Link added in case it helps.

Comment: What is the type of `function_A`? Where did its value come from?

Comment: This is the prototype `void function_A(int value, int value2);`

Comment: Then that code is wrong, it will compare the function pointer and not the opcode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot dereference a function pointer to get at the underlying code.

This is probably done by introducing a different pointer, and relying on the particular platform "doing the right thing", where "right" means "what I want to do".

Something like:

```
const unsigned char *function_A = (unsigned char *) printf; /* Any function. */
```

This is not portable, and will generate compiler warnings since function and data pointers are not compatible. On e.g. x86, it will probably "work".

Comment: Well, where the ABI says something different from the Standard, should we still stay language lawyers and insist that it isn't correct? (I mean, people are writing shell code that works with a reasonable explanation.) (And I'm not trying to be trolling here, just interested.)

Comment: And +1 anyway. From another point of view: under POSIX, `void *` is compatible with both data and function pointers. This means that `void *tmp = &printf; const unsigned char *funcPtr = tmp;` works without a warning.

Comment: The assignment may work without a warning, but will it perform, what a reader of the code thinks it should do?

Comment: It will work on all flat memory models where code and data memory are "equivalent". In other architectures, such as where data and code memory are completely separate, then it probably won't. Since I stopped working on 16-bit x86 and 8-bit 8051/8031 systems, I have not worked on a processor that you can't just convert the address of code to a data pointer and at least read it. But I'm sure such systems do still exist in some embedded parts of the world, and possibly some ancient machines may also have separate code and data spaces, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you do something like this:

```
unsigned char *pf; 

pf = (unsigned char *)function_A;

if (*pf == 0xE9)
{ 
...
}
```

then you would get that effect (assuming the architecture allows reading code in general, and the compiler does the right undefined behaviour to achieve this).

However, unless you scan the entire function in your code, one could quite easily bypass such a detection scheme by putting the jump instruction (0xe9 is a jump to a relative address) somewhere else, or using a different form of jump instruction (0x66 0xe9, and a 16 or 32 bit offset in a 32 respectively 16 bit architecture, for example). And of course, if you like to only override the scoring function inside a longer function, modifying a few bytes within that function to change `score += 10` to `score += 120` wouldn't be too hard. It's possible that changing to `score += 10000` may be harder, since there are often "small number" and "large number" variants of the add and subtract instructions.